# Problem with request.security_lower_tf() function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm struggeling with the request.security_lower_tf() function if I use the tradingview replay. If the replay plays, I'm only getting the last intrabar from the lower timeframe.

Comment: This is a known bug with replay and `security()` function, TradingView is aware of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue still persists. The value on shows complete on the last bar on where the Replay Mode starts. But as long as you play it, it starts removing the values until none is left. I hope they could explain they it's not giving or recalculating the values on every bar.